# Timezone Rails Postgres

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, select, timezone

How to select datetime column with timezone using ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute()?

e.g

`User.first.joined_at => Tue, 31 Jul 2018 05:00:34 MSK +03:00`

but

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT joined_at FROM users") => {"joined_at"=>"2018-07-31 02:00:34.684659"}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` doesn't understand the database's types that well so you have to parse the strings yourself.

That timestamp should be in UTC as that's the Rails standard inside the database. You could go through `Time.zone`:

```
Time.zone = 'UTC' # Unless your application is already in UTC
t = Time.zone.parse('2018-07-31 02:00:34.684659').in_time_zone('Moscow')
# Tue, 31 Jul 2018 05:00:34 MSK +03:00
```

Or you could go through `DateTime` (which assumes UTC if the string doesn't have a timezone embedded in it):

```
DateTime.parse('2018-07-31 02:00:34.684659').in_time_zone('Moscow')
# Tue, 31 Jul 2018 05:00:34 MSK +03:00
```